# Measuring influence of execution time with wait?

Tags: java, performance

I'm working on a project that measures the influence of calcuation time of a certain method on performance of certain frameworks. I was wondering whether a sleep() with varying time would suffice to do that? Especially for the fork/join framework, which is massively thread-parallel, a sleep() should wait x real seconds. I mean that when thread Y is executing, the sleep for thread Z, which is then not executing, should not count. The sleep should keep the processor locked for the current thread so to speak.

Basically: will a sleep(x) sleep for x effective execution-time seconds or will it count time when the thread is idle too?

I can't find any info online, probably because I don't know the right terminology because it looks like a fairly basic question.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep() puts the thread to sleep as the name suggests. It deliberately and purposely stops the thread and the OS possibly starts it on another cpu when it wakes.

Its not clear what you are trying to do, or while you need threads locked to a core if you are going to put them to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

sleep() does not keep the processor locked on the current thread, processor leaves the thread in inactive state and continues working with other threads.